# How can I merge team A and team B into a single record that share the same match ID?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm building a football database and have a team table and a fixture table (amongst many others of course..).

There are two records for a single fixture, one for team A and one for team B. So for example:

```
ID: 0
Team: Arsenal
Result: Win

ID 0
Team: Chelsea
Result: Loss
```

Firstly is this the best approach to this? Or should a fixture be a single record with two columns for two teams?

Secondly, how can I combine this data when it comes to queries. For example if I wanted to return all fixtures involving Arsenal to give me:

```
ID: 0
Team 1: Arsenal
Team 2: Chelsea
Result: Win
```

Just a point in the right direction would be brilliant.

Really appreciate the help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table structure you show looks more like a data transfer format.

For long term storage and querying you would probably separate it in two tables:

- team:

  - id
  - name
- match:

  - match_id
  - local_team_id
  - visitor_team_id
  - result

Otherwise even simple queries like the one you are asking about become unnecessary convoluted.

Comment: Though `result` could also be an `id` from `team`. Like `victor_id` or something.Because you can't put 'win` in `result` because that's not the right information.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with Impaler the structure of the table can be better to avoid future issues like this. But back to your question the only way i could find to pull the exact result set that you have is to have two derived table where one is filtered by the results. I have one for winners and one for the losing team. From there I joined the tables together and pull the necessary info. Hope this helps. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/967db/1/0

```
SELECT
    tb1.id
    ,tb1.team AS 'team 1'
    ,tb2.team AS 'team 2'
    ,tb1.result
From
(SELECT
    * 
FROM 
dbo.teams
WHERE result LIKE 'win') AS tb1
JOIN 
(SELECT
    * 
FROM 
dbo.teams
WHERE result LIKE 'loss') tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id
```